# Why does SQlite return incorrect sum?

Tags: sqlite, sum

```
CREATE TABLE "Test" ("ItemQty" DOUBLE NOT NULL );

Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);
Insert Into Test VALUES (1.4);



Select Sum(ItemQty)
From Test;
```

Result: 15.400000000000002

Should be 15.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type **DOUBLE** is a floating point type represented in binary internally. Binary floating point numbers will produce "rounding errors" when converted to base 10. If you want precise numeric calculations with a decimal point, you'll have to use the **NUMERIC** or **DECIMAL** type.

To help you understand why floating point types have rounding errors when converting to base 10, please see this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Also, just for your reference, the **NUMERIC** or **DECIMAL** types are going to be orders of magnitude slower at calculations compared to the **DOUBLE** type.

Also see [Data Types in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: SQLite does not have NUMERIC or DECIMAL data types.

Comment: @efesar Why don't you modify your answer given that SQLite does *not* support NUMERIC or DECIMAL?

Answer (score -1):

```
select printf('%.2d',Sum(ItemQty))
```

should be

```
select printf('%.2f',Sum(ItemQty))
```